# (Rails 7) status: What is it/does it do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

Upgraded to rails 7, working on an invitation system where I have a nested hierarchy
Routes:

```
  resources :invites do 
    resources :guests
  end
```

Invite Model has :   `has_many :guests, dependent: :destroy`
Guest Model has : `belongs_to :invite`

Issue specific code from guests_controller.rb:

```
  def destroy
    @invite = Invite.find(params[:invite_id])
    @guest = Guest.find(params[:id])
    @guest.destroy

    redirect_to invite_path(@invite)#, status: :see_other
  end
```

When I don't include the `status: :see_other` Rails deletes Guests associated with that Invitation, and the invitation itself.
But if I include it. It works as expected by deleting only the selected Guest entry.

What exactly does the 'status:' do. I can't find a satisfying answer as of yet.

Comment: Can you explain about `:see_other` ?

Comment: No, I just 'grabbed it from the internet' and it just works, I don't know what makes this works, why it wasn't needed in earlier projects (Rails 6), but now it is.

Comment: :see_status explained here:  http://www.railsstatuscodes.com/see_other.html

Comment: @Michael Probably without `see_other` browser issues DELETE instead of GET to invite_url, hence it is deleted (because in InvitesController you have `destroy` method which responds to it).

Answer (score 1):

`see_other` - 303 HTTP status code. It is a way to redirect the application to another `URI`.

When to use `see_other` status?

If the response to the request is another URI using a `GET` method.

Referral [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) for in-depth understanding!!

Answer (score 1):

The `destroy` action fetches the guest from the database, and calls `destroy` on it

Then, the browser redirects to the invite path with status code `303 See Other`. The status 303 provides a redirect with the `GET` method after the perform some another HTTP verb (`DELETE` in your case)

If you doesn't specify this status, browser redirects to a new location with `DELETE` method. You probably have route for invitation destroy, that's why invitation is destroyed automagically

Rails 7 works this way, official rails [guide recommends](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#deleting-an-article) to specify such status

Please also see [official docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to)

> The status code can either be a standard HTTP Status code as an integer, or a symbol representing the downcased, underscored and symbolized description. Note that the status code must be a 3xx HTTP code, or redirection will not occur.
>
> If you are using XHR requests other than GET or POST and redirecting after the request then some browsers will follow the redirect using the original request method. This may lead to undesirable behavior such as a double DELETE. To work around this you can return a `303 See Other status` code which will be followed using a GET request.